# How can I load images efficiently while hiding the actual image url?

Tags: php, laravel

So in the following code I have to query the database each time for every image. It's quite slow. Is there a way to do this in a single query while keeping the actual image urls hidden like I currently have in the blade file?

Blade:

```
<img src="/image/1">
<img src="/image/2">
<img src="/image/3">
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/image/{id}', [ImageController::class, 'image']);
```

Controller:

```
public function image($id)
{
    $img = DB::where('id', '=', $id)
        ->select('path', 'filename', 'extension')
        ->first();

    $image_path = $img->path.'/'.$img->filename.$img->extension;

    return response()->file( $image_path );
}
```

I'm basically getting the links from the database and the images should be accessible without having to login. I just want to hide the filename without having to change the actual filename to hash ids. The reason for this is because the filenames help me identify what I'm looking at. I just want to hide the filenames in the browser while not having to sacrifice performance.

Comment: If you're doing this approach, it will be 1 DB query for each Image, every page load. You might want to use something like a View Composer to load the images from your database once, iterate and display them, something like `@foreach($images as $image) <img src="{{ $image->imagePath }}"/> @endforeach`. This will hide the `/image/{id}` URL (and make it completely unnecessary), but if that's still not enough, you could also base64-encode them, then `<img src="{{ $base64EncodedString }}"/>` wouldn't show _any_ URL. That's just my 2¢'s though.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Could you go into more detail about the View Composer? I'm not familiar with what that is. Is that related to Laravel Views, blade files?

Comment: Sure thing! A [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#view-composers) is arbitrary code that is run whenever a specific View is rendered. If those Images are in a Partial that is used in multiple places, then a View Composer is a good way to load the Images for it. If it's only really used once, you can do the same thing in a Controller. But basically, it calls whatever code it needs to, in your case, a single Query to get images `1, 2, 3`, then passes them to the view so you can call `@foreach($images as $image)` instead of hard-coding `/image/1`, `/image/2` and `/image/3` 

Comment: Man, that sounds like a perfect solution. Could you create an answer laying out all the steps in detail? I'll probably choose yours as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a perfect candidate for a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#view-composers):

`app\Composers\ImageComposer.php` (New file in new Folder `app\Composers`)

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers\Composers;

use App\Models\Image;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class ImageComposer {
  public function compose(View $view) {
    // Note: Important to use an `Image` model here for extended functionality
    $images = Image::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();

    return $view->with(['images' => $images]);
  }
}
```

`app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`) (Existing File)

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Providers\Composers\ImageComposer;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
  public function boot() {
    view()->composer('images', ImageComposer::class);
  }
}
```

`app\Models\Image.php` (New or Existing Model)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model {
  public function getDisplayPathAttribute() {
    return $this->path. '/' . $this->filename . $this->extension;
  }

  public function getBase64EncodedStringAttribute() {
    return 'data:image/' . $this->extension . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($this->display_path));
  }
}
```

`images.blade.php` (Existing file where your `/images/1`, etc. code is)

```html
@foreach($images as $image)
  <img src="{{ $image->display_path }}"/>
  <!-- OR -->
  <img src="{{ $image->base64_encoded_string }}"/>
@endforeach
```

The basic logic here is that `images.blade.php` is a `view`, the Composer creates an `$images` variable, which you can then iterate over and fill in the `src` property with `display_path`, which is an Accessor on your `Image` model for returning the full path. Any time you render the `images.blade.php` view, either via `@include('images')`, or `view('images')`, etc., it will have `$images` available.

Comment: I'll go try this out. Also how do you do the base64-encode?

Comment: I _think_ that should work; `base64_encode` the `file_get_contents` from the Image's path, and use that as `src="{{ $image->base64_encoded_string }}"` instead .

Comment: Is the 'images' in app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php for pointing at the images.blade.php? It's because my blade file isn't called image.blade.php so I was wondering which parts are pointing to it?

Comment: Yes, the `'images'` part of `view()->composer('images', ImageComposer::class);` is the name of the view you're passing this to; adjust as required  On the other hand, the `'images'` part of `$view->with(['images' => $images]);` is the variable name that will be available in the View, which you can also adjust to whatever.

Comment: On this line, `Image::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();` Should I be changing `Image` to the corresponding Model where I get the image data? Oh, I guess I should be extending Image from my Model.

Comment: What is `Image` in this context? `Image::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();` It looks like `Image` needs to be the part that accesses the database here but I have a different model which has the image data in it.

Initially I tried to extend the existing model with Image but it already extends Model class so I wasn't sure what to do.

Comment: *"app\Models\Image.php (New or Existing Model)"* - `Image` is a Model, if you don't have one, you'll need to add one, but if you do have one, all you need to do is add the 2 methods `getDisplayPathAttribute` and `getBase64EncodedStringAttribute`. Your original code `DB::where(...)->select(...)->first()` is missing `::table(...)`, so I assumed you have an `images` table. Just adjust as necessary; that is all basic Model stuff, nothing fancy.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting, `Undefined variable $images`. This is happening in `images.blade.php`

Comment: Hmm, you'll have to debug why; that simply means somewhere along the chain, something isn't happening. Check these: 1) you have `AppServiceProvider` in `config/app.php`, 2) you've run `composer dump-autoload` (sometimes not necessary, but doesn't hurt to run), 3) you've restarted `php artisan serve` (or whatever is running your webserver), etc. If that still fails, drop a `dd($images);` in your `ImageComposer` and see if the code is being hit.

Comment: 1) looks good. 2) done 3) added `dd($images);` right after `$images = Image::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();` but still the same error but the line `view()->composer('images', ImageComposer::class);` is definitely in boot() within `AppServiceProvider`.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed I got a warning with composer dump-autoload. It says `Class App\Providers\Composers\ImageComposer located in ./app/Composers/ImageComposer.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.`

Comment: I changed the namespace for ImageComposer to `namespace App\Composers;` from `namespace App\Providers\Composers;` and `composer dump-autoload` worked without any warnings but still the same error.

Comment: Well I did say "New file in **`app\Composers`**", but you put it in `app\Providers\Composers`, so the namespace doesn't match. Fix it to be one or the other; it doesn't matter where you put it, as long as it is consistent and uses the same path as it's namespace.

Comment: Hmm... Take a second and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73447682/edit) with the new code (add it all under your existing code) so I can see what's happening; I'll try to recreate it locally; I must have missed something.

Comment: It just never reaches the compose() function that's in ImageComposer. What calls the compose() function?

Comment: `view()->composer('images', ImageComposer::class);` _should_ call the `compose` method, unless I missed something 

Comment: Hmm, I checked with dd() and it definitely goes through boot() in AppServiceProvider but nothing happens when I place a dd in the compose() function in ImageComposer. And this line `view()->composer('images', ImageComposer::class);` isn't causing any errors.

Comment: I have no idea what is going on with your setup, but a minimal example works fine in a Laravel Sandbox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfInF.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHatO.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx3hd.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAbqO.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytfTo.png

Comment: The only thing that's different is the namespace App\Providers\Composers; in ImageComposer. Should that matter?

Comment: Could this be an issue? 'view()->composer('/images/{page}', ImageComposer::class);'

Comment: It needs to match the folder structure; if you put `ImageComposer.php` in `app\Providers\Composers`, then it should be `namespace App\Providers\Composers;`. If you put it in `app\Composers`, then it should be `namespace App\Composers`. Make it consistent.

Comment: Yes, `'view()->composer('/images/{page}', ImageComposer::class);' ` is an issue. `images/{page}` isn't a valid filename. You don't have a `images.{page}.blade.php` file (and you can't).

Comment: Once again, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73447682/edit); these are things I can catch if I can see them 

Comment: Thank you. Ok, couple things, Model names are Singular, `JsonCard`, not `JsonCards` (can also remove `protected $table = 'json_cards';` if you change that), `getDisplayPathAttribute` is wrong (you need to use the code you were calling before, not `return $this->card_name;`), but otherwise, looks ok to me, assuming everything is in the correct folders and has the correct namespace. Are you still getting the error?

Comment: Yeah, it's still the same error. If you look at the solution, `namespace App\Providers\Composers;` even though the folder is `app\Composers`. Can that matter?

Comment: Or if the card-grid route is taking in attributes, could that matter?

Comment: Fix the namespace; I assumed you did that already since you didn't include them in your edit  The rest of that is irrelevant. Is your `card-grid.blade.php` in a subfolder? You'll need to reference it properly if it is, like `view()->compose('path.to.card-grid', ImageComposer::class)`. Then it should all work. I'm making a lot of assumptions on basic Laravel stuff that I guess I shouldn't be...

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. It was because the path for the view was incorrect. It should have been 'grid/card-grid' but it was 'card-grid'.

Comment: Everything works! Thank you!

Comment: Hooray! I should have guess it was that; if the code was working, but not affecting the view, it makes sense that you were referencing the view file incorrectly. Glad it's all working now, cheers!

Comment: I realize this displays the filenames and path? Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: That's why the `base64` solution is there too; use that if you don't want those to show up. Side question though, why is that an issue? There shouldn't be any sensitive information in a filename/path; you have total control over that when uploading the Image.

Comment: When I use the base64 solution it was just loading forever for some reason. As for the filename, it's useful to myself to know what the file contents are without having to open it. I could create a hash for all the filenames but I would have to open the image to see what it is. Was the base64 working for you?

Comment: *"loading forever for some reason"* - There's a lot of possible reasons... Where you're storing your images, might be missing a `public_path()` (or similar), etc. Please consider asking a new question, and include all those details. This question already has a reasonable and accepted answer, changing either of those is not how Stackoverflow is meant to operate. Also no, that `base64` approach is not tested; I don't do the same thing as you when it comes to images; mine are stored in S3, I can pull them, read the file and encode it without issue, but the code is different.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.